# htaccess redirect when entering path in address bar

Tags: php

I want to move some files to another directory on my web server, but these files are images,
that my clients link to. I have not got the time to go and change over 100 image urls, so is there a way i can get .htaccess file to do a mod_rewrite to point then image url to where it should be?

Thanks

Fero

Answer (score 1):

You can limit this on the server side.

One way it to check the referer header if it matches with your site.

The other is to use a special loading mechanism between the server and flash that passes some sort of token or HTTP authentication, and maybe protect the token/auth with SSL.

Whatever you choose it will not be 100% bullet proof and IMO is not worth the hustle.

Comment: Note that the referer header is optional and some personal security software modifies it. You can't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's rather the point of mod_rewrite.

If you are just moving a directory wholesale, then a simple redirect will be easier though.

```
Redirect 301 /old/images/ http://example.com/new/images/
```

Comment: David.. I am not moving the directory wholesale. I need just if any one type the path in the address bar then "FORBIDDEN" page should be redirected. Awaiting for the answer. thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question you asked.

Comment: Hang on. When you say "FORBIDDEN" do you mean "NOT FOUND"? I don't think you can trap that in mod_rewrite. You could set up a mod_perl handler, PHP script or similar as your ErrorHandler document though.

Comment: http://www.splocs.com/images/ Please use the above URL. This is exactly what i need...

Comment: You want to disable the directory index? That's one of the settings of the Options property in the Apache configuration.

Comment: But i did using .htaccess. But in the mean time if i enter the name of the image following by the path the image is displaying. This should not happen. Any better way to do.

Comment: In simple images in my project should be protected.

Comment: Might as well just delete them from the server then. You can't let people use images in a webpage but not let them view the images outside the page.